# type mismatch error while running ml.PredictionModel in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

After training all the model, i am trying to rename each model prediction column to uniquely identify the model prediction inside the dataset.I am getting type mismatch error as specified below :

`import org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel`

`import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`

`val models = Seq(("NB", nbModel), ("DT", dtModel), ("RF", rfModel), ("GBM",gbmModel))`

its output is given below:

`models: Seq[(String, Any)] = List((NB,NaiveBayesModel (uid=nb_699528805899)` `with 2 classes), (DT,()), (RF,RandomForestClassificationModel` `(uid=rfc_403e93000cb6) with 10 trees), (GBM,GBTClassificationModel` `(uid=gbtc_e778e2781d0b) with 20 trees))`

`def mlData(inputData: DataFrame, responseColumn: String, baseModels:`

```
  Seq[(String, PredictionModel[_, _])]): DataFrame= {

  baseModels.map{ case(name, model) =>

  model.transform(inputData)

  .select("row_id", model.getPredictionCol )

  .withColumnRenamed("prediction", s"${name}_prediction")

  }.reduceLeft((a, b) =>a.join(b, Seq("row_id"), "inner"))

  .join(inputData.select("row_id", responseColumn), Seq("row_id"),

  "inner")

}
```

its output is given below:

`mlData: (inputData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, responseColumn: String, baseModels: Seq[(String, org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel[_, _])])`
`org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`

`val mlTrainData= mlData(transferData, "value", models).drop("row_id")`

i am getting type mismatch error, that actually should not had occurred

`<console>:102: error: type mismatch;`
 `found   : Seq[(String, Any)]`
`required: Seq[(String, org.apache.spark.ml.PredictionModel[_, _])]`
       `val mlTrainData= mlData(transferData, "value", models).drop("row_id")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just based on the output it is clear that the second element in the `DT` tuple is `Unit` not a `PredictionModel` - that's why whole object is `Seq[(_, Any)]` and your code fails.

Since you don't provide context it is not clear how you get there.

Comment: if i type only "models"  without "" , i am getting  models
res57: Seq[(String, Any)] = List((NB,NaiveBayesModel (uid=nb_699528805899) with 2 classes), (DT,()), (RF,RandomForestClassificationModel (uid=rfc_403e93000cb6) with 10 trees), (GBM,GBTClassificationModel (uid=gbtc_e778e2781d0b) with 20 trees)) 
and it have the PredictionModel required